# How to set background image for popup menu in android?

Tags: android, popupmenu

Well i have listed outed the items in the listview in popup menu, right now i need to customize my popup view with background layout back of the listview. Is it possible i tried through surfing in net but i can't find a solution. Advance thanks.

my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="add"
        android:visible="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="delete"
        android:visible="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="edit"
        android:visible="true"/>

</menu>
```

whant i want in my code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try this
yourButtonViewObject is the button onwhich you click to show this popupwindow

```
ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(
            ListPopupWindowAppActivity.this);

//here you can set your custom adapter aswell
        listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(
            ListPopupWindowAppActivity.this,
            R.layout.list_item, passyourarrayhere));
        listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(yourButtonViewObject);
        listPopupWindow.setWidth(300);
        listPopupWindow.setHeight(400);

listPopupWindow.setModal(true);
        listPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(
            ListPopupWindowAppActivity.this);

//when you click on yourButtonViewObject show listPopupWindow like this
listPopupWindow.show();

//and in onItemClick overiden method do similar as you do in listview
```